# Windows 7 is not showing any text in aero theme

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Yesterday I ran `sfc /scannow` command in cmd for fixing corrupted files. It told me to reboot and I did it. When I reboot it shown something like "Applying changes , 30 of 30 , HKLM/Software" etc after Starting windows text on same screen. But it was interrupted for some reason before it completed. When I opened my computer today I couldn't see any text on windows 7 even the Please wait , welcome messages or desktop icons. But I can see it on High contrast or other themes. How to fix it?
Edit: I cant open C:/Windows/Fonts. When I open this folder I get a blue screen which says `BAD_POOL_HEADER` and 0* something and somany text which makes my computer restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the fonts in windows 7 got corrupted while interrupting windows update. So I ran `sfc /SCANNOW` more than one time and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you made a full backup of the system before running the SFC command. Restoring to that is your best option.

If you don't have a backup, try booting to Safe Mode, then removing the video card driver. Reboot normally and let PnP find your video card. Then install the native driver from the manufactrurer.

Comment: Perhaps a restore point was auto-created, so might be worth trying System Restore too.

Comment: I dont have a restore point